# C# is very slow with kepware

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, plc

I have a C# form application that communicate with PLC via Kepware OPC Server.
But this communication slowdown my GUI. I use thread for communication but form tabpages still very slow. I am sending a part of my code. Where am I wrong?

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Connect_Opc_Server("Kepware.KEPServerEX.V5");
     ConnectToSqlToRead();
     ShowPartType(1);
}

private void timer_Kepware_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Thread KepwareThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Kepware_Read_Write));
     if (KepwareThread.IsAlive)
     { }
     else
     {
         KepwareThread.Start();
     }
 }

public void Kepware_Read_Write()
{
    if (KepwarePLCReadError == false)
    {
        synch_read();
    }

    if (KepwarePLCReadOK == true)
    {
        synch_write();
    }           
}
```

Comment: How often is your `tick` event getting fired?

Comment: You should be using the subscription API and the data changed callbacks to get your data, polling is very innefficient. I have a lot of experience using Kepware and TopServer (same as Kepware) in my applications.

Comment: You might be better off using a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).  It's  a bit easier to use & troubleshoot and is designed to work with WinForms applications.

Comment: on every 100 ms. Yes because thread is read all datas from plc and after that it kills

Comment: You can remove redundant compare for `boolean`: `if (KepwarePLCReadOK == true)` is simply `if(KepwarePLCReadOK)`, and `if (KepwarePLCReadError == false)` is `if (!KepwarePLCReadError)`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create only 1 thread.

```
private void timer_Kepware_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_KepwareThread == null)
    {
        _KepwareThread = new Thread(...);
    } 
    if (!_KepwareThread.IsAlive) 
    {
        _KewpareThread.Start();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think it needs to look like

`if (_KepwareThread == null) {_KepwareThread = new Thread(...);}

if (!_KepwareThread.IsAlive) {_KewpareThread.Start();}`

Comment: true - I saw it earlier and I knew I need to fix it.